# Дефис между несколькими существительными

Tags: раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова

Нужно ли ставить дефис между всеми тремя словами в предложении "2D экшн платформер" или только между "экшн" и "платформер"? Какое при этом правило применяется?

Спасибо = )